# ACCESS file connection from EXCEL to SharePoint (SQL database)

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, connection

I have an access connection file (.accdb) that allows me to use EXCEL (Office 365) to query a SharePoint Library.  It all works great EXCEPT for new files added to that SharePoint Library.  I can query for and return all data for these new files/entries but cannot get the filename for these new entries for some reason.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Const SQLIMSSHAREPOINTCONNECTION = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\MORGAN\MACROS\IMS_SHAREPOINT_db.accdb"

Sub routine:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim StrSql As String
Dim thePieces1() As String
Dim thePieces2() As String
Dim theFullFilename As String
Dim theShortFilename As String
       
StrSql = "SELECT [Name], [ID], [PartNumber(s)], [DateCompleted], [DocumentType], " & _
        "[WorkOrder(s)], [PurchaseOrder(s)], [SalesOrder(s)], [CustomerName(s)], [WorkCenter]" & _
        " FROM [Inspection Reports]"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open SQLIMSSHAREPOINTCONNECTION
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Open StrSql
If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then

    i = 1

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Not rs.EOF

        i = i + 1
        theFullFilename = ""
        theShortFilename = ""
        ReDim thePieces1(10)

        thePieces1 = Split(rs.Fields(0), "#")
        theFullFilename = thePieces1(1)
        thePieces1() = Split(theFullFilename, "/")
        theShortFilename = thePieces1(UBound(thePieces1))

        Range("A" & i).Value = rs.Fields(1)      ' ID
        Range("B" & i).Value = theShortFilename  ' Filename
        Range("C" & i).Value = rs.Fields(2)      ' PartNumber(s)
        Range("D" & i).Value = rs.Fields(3)      ' DateCompleted
        Range("E" & i).Value = rs.Fields(4)      ' DocumentType
        Range("F" & i).Value = rs.Fields(5)      ' WorkOrder(s)
        Range("G" & i).Value = rs.Fields(6)      ' PurchaseOrder(s)
        Range("H" & i).Value = rs.Fields(7)      ' CustomerName
        Range("I" & i).Value = rs.Fields(8)      ' WorkCenter

        rs.MoveNext
        
    Loop
```

Comment: Maybe show an example of what you mean, This code issues results of some kind, and you can always add print debugging to show what various values are. [Edit] the question and show what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me how your sharepoint access Excel connection works, but your  recordset (rs) probably needs a refresh or requery after you updated the sharepoint data.

Comment: Thank you for idea but I actually tried "activewoorkbook.refreshall" and it did not make a difference.  I will try to figure out how to attach a notepad (text) file of my code (streamlined to just the pertinient stuff of course).

Comment: Odd thing is that EXCEL connection to SharePoint does see all the metadata EXCEPT for the filename.  So it sees the newly added LIbrary entry but does not show me the filename for some reason.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).